# Laravel passport - logout user via api

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-passport

I'm running a laravel API with a login page and a nuxt.js application which authenticates a user through oauth.

The whole authorization flow is working, but after successfully logging out in the nuxt.js app a user is not asked for user credentials anymore on further logins.

How can I manage that the user is asked for his credentials again on next login?

Question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318310/how-to-logout-a-user-from-api-using-laravel-passport) but I don't want to delete any authorization tokens, I want user to again login.

I already created a custom endpoint in my api but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    public function logoutApi()
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        $cookie = \Cookie::forget('laravel_session');
        \Session::flush();

        return response('User has been logged out.')->cookie($cookie);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't want to delete the authorization tokens?

Comment: So far I know deleting auth token is part of oauth flow

Comment: @fez because if I delete the auth token user has just to again click on a "Authorize" button, not completely log in

Comment: Btw session::flush will delete all user access

Answer (score 0):

This will revoke a user's access to the token but the token won't be deleted

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $user = Auth::user()->token();
    $user->revoke();
}
```

Comment: It also needs `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`