# Passport and Auth::logout() produces an unexpected error

Tags: laravel-passport, laravel-6.2

I am using **Laravel 6.7 with Passport** to consume my own API. When I try to logout a user using `Auth::logout()`, I get the following error:

> Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not exist.

I don't understand why I get such behavior. I haven't used any custom guards. My **Auth.php** as per the Passport Setup is as follows:

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

This is my AuthenticationController.php where the logout code resides:

```
/**
     * --------------------------------------------------
     * Removes the identity of a users login session.
     * --------------------------------------------------
     * @param Request $request
     * @return MessageResource
     * --------------------------------------------------
     */
    public function logout(Request $request): MessageResource
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            Auth::user()->token()->revoke();
        }
        return new MessageResource(['message' => 'Logout request is successful.']);
    }
```

Is there any way to solve this issue? Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's already solved please do some research then ask question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43318310/how-to-logout-a-user-from-api-using-laravel-passport

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Auth::logout()` is for `web guard`.Here, you are using API guard so delete token of authorization it'll automatically logout from you application.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->token()->revoke();
    //$request->user()->token()->delete(); for delete.
    //Auth::user()->token()->revoke(); same way as revoke user token
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully logged out'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: After looking everywhere, this was the correct way to do this. Finally no errors! Thank you.

Comment: For me just revoking the token does not work. I get the Auth::user() as last authenticated user. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->token()->revoke();
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully logged out'
    ]);
}
```